# (ORB_SLAM3) ROS stereo-inertial ORB_SLAM3 producing "segmation fault (core dumped)" crash randomly during operation

Tags: orb, slam

After numerous failed attempts of building all dependencies and the algorithm itself (with no prior experience of programming), I finally got the algorithm running on my ubuntu 18.04 machine. Sadly after recording my own dataset with an T265 and using the stereo-inertial ROS node to stream data to, the ORB_SLAM3 algorithm randomly produces the "Segmentation fault (core dumped) error" with no extra information regarding the error. Weirdly this can occur on the start, near the end or not at all during the SLAM process which makes it very hard to determine the exact reason for this error. Has somebody experienced this before and knows a way to fix this?

Error:
First KF:1; Map init KF:0
New Map created with 30 points
start VIBA 1
end VIBA 1
start VIBA 2
end VIBA 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I've tried adjusting the settingsfile with no to little result next to looking at solutions specified by other users but no issue seems to match my error. The only thing in my mind that can cause the error is the rosbag playrate as this is set to 0.5 because the algorithm on my setup can't handle the 30fps datastream (the "Camera.fps" and "IMU.Frequency" parameters are adjusted accordingly) but I'm not an expert.

Your help is much appreciated!